# Custom single page based on which custom page template is selected

Tags: customization, pages, templates, single

I have two custom page templates ("template-blog-left.php" with the sidebar of the left side, and "template-blog-right.php" with the sidebar on the right side.) but I don't know if there's any way of creating a custom single post template for each of them, so that If I select the "template-blog-left.php" for my "Blog" page, then the single page should have the sidebar on the left.

So, in other words, is it possible to have a custom single page being selected automatically every time I make a post, based on the custom page template that is selected for the "Blog" page.

Comment: you said you have "template-blog-left.php template which have sidebar in left, so automatically if you will assign this template to any post it will have a sidebar in left .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible using [`get_template_part();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)

Assuming that you use a standard single.php:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template name: template-blog-left
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="left-sidebar">
  <!-- Here your left sidebar -->
</div>

<div id="content">
  <?php 
        //This function will look for single.php file in your theme folder
        get_template_part( 'single' );
   ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: @DanielSarmas, you're welcome